# Making a flexbox shrink regardless of content (possible chrome bug)

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, flexbox

I have a basic layout which looks like this:

```css
#first {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

#second {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}

#third {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="third">
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ars0bug2/)

Safari, Firefox and Opera all have expected behavior. When resizing the window, all divs shrink and a scrollbar appears in the third div.

This also worked fine in Chrome until the last update. Now the first and second divs work as expected, but the third div doesn't completely shrink (because of its content) and exceeds its container on the bottom.

Did I just find a Chrome bug? Or are Firefox, Opera and Safari just more flexible with this kind of layout? How can I force the third div to shrink and respect the `overflow` property in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `overflow: scroll` to the second div:

```css
#first {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

#second {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}

#third {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="third">
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
          TEST<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ars0bug2/1/)